# Куда пропадает list при вызове на нем метода append() в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Почему встроенная функция `list()` не возвращает объект типа `<class 'list'>` если сразу на возвращаемом объекте применить метод `append()`? P.S. Python 3.7.2

Пример:

```py
s = 'mystr'
l = list().append(s)
```

Компилятор и runtime не выдаст никаких ошибок, но при этом метод `append()` ничего не зааппендит, а `print(l)` выведет `None`. Т.е. Значение `l` будет типа `<class 'NoneType'>`.

Но, если посмотреть, то встроенная функция `list()` без параметров возвращает тип `<class 'list'>` к которому нет причин не применить встроенный метод `append()`.

Куда пропадает `list`?

Comment: Значение выражения list().append(s) - это то значение, которое возвращает метод append, а этот метод не возвращает созданный список.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, да, точно, это метод `append()` возвращает `NoneType`, а на объект типа `list` получается ссылка теряется? То есть, новый созданный объект подберёт GC?

Comment: Да, созданный список в выражении не присваивается ни одной переменной.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, интересно, чем авторы Python руководствовались, что не могли сделать возврат ссылки на самого себя из метода `append()`? Запись кода приведенного выше является обычным для некоторых объектных ЯП.

Comment: Скорей всего они копировали дизайн контейнеров, который уже приинят во многих других языках программирования. Так, например, в C++ многие методы контейнера  vector также не возвращают ссылку на исходный контейнер, а имеют тип void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возвращаемым значением выражения `list().append(s)` является то значение, которое возвращает метод `append`. А этот метод не возвращает список.

Поэтому ссылка на созданный в этом выражении список не будет сохранена ни в одной переменной.